# `javac` doesn't see Android support library when building Android application manually

Tags: java, android, jar

I build Android application manually from command line. I use `javac` to compile it. Everything is OK when I don't use Android Support V4 library. For any reason, `javac` doesn't see this jar file.

My command line follows:

`"c:\Program Files\Java\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation -Xlint:-options -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -d classes -cp "C:\Users\Developer\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar";"C:\Users\Developer\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\23.4.0\support-v4-23.4.0-sources.jar";"C:\Users\Developer\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar";classes -sourcepath java @fileslist.txt`

Here I put reference to `"C:\Users\Developer\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\23.4.0\support-v4-23.4.0-sources.jar"`, it is path to Android Support v4 library. The `jar` file exists, and when I open it with Java decompiler, I see that it contains `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` class definition. However, `javac` doesn't see it, and I receive following error:

`error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist`

What is the reason? Has `javac` any limits on `jar` files count, or on command line length, etc?

Comment: *it is path to Android Support v4 library* no, it is a path to Android Support v4 library's **source** ... edit: you may try unpack **support-v4-23.4.0.aar** get **classes.jar** and **libs/internal_impl-23.4.0.jar**  from there and compile with those to jars... but i'm not sure if it would works

Comment: You right, when I unpacked `aar` file, Java started to accept it. New errors occurred (because support-v4 has dependencies that have to be extracted also), however, it solves the issue with `jar` file, so I used wrong `jar`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating a similar but different issue. I wish to but not need to point to the entire support folder. My APK compiled but breaks down with AppCompatActivity but runs fine with Activity.

On the other hand, you need to copy your jars to your project's "libs" directory, then add the extdirs option when running the java compiler. To that option add the "libs" directory, like so;

```
copy C:\...\support-v4-23.4.0-sources.jar <path to project>\libs\support-v4-23.4.0-sources.jar

javac @normal_options -extdir <path to project>\libs\ @sources
```

Your project should compile OK. But you may be in the same predicament as I am in. I am unsure if the support library has wide spanning dependencies. Copying the one jar left me in my current predicament.